# Combine matrices using Mat opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have 2 matrices as follows

```
    R = [1,0,0,0
         0,1,0,0
         0,0,1,0
         0,0,0,1]
```

and

```
   T = [1,0,0]
```

Can I make a 4X4 Matrix from the above 2 in this format?

```
    [    R | T
     0 0 0   1]
```

This is basically obtaining the transformation matrix from the rotation and translation. I am trying using for loops and combining them into one matrix. But is there an easy way or a function that can help me do this in a shorter way?

Comment: In your example R is 4x4 and T is 1x3 matrix. How you can do `R|T` (the dimensions don't agree)? Can you show the desired result for your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to approach this. You can create an output matrix first and then operate on a rectangular sub-regions of the output (ROI – “Region of Interest”):

1. Allocate a matrix that will keep the result. Fill in the matrix with desired initial values (optional). Make sure the matrix has the correct dimension and data type. For example:

   ```
   // create output matrix
   // rows and cols specify the disired size for the output matrix
   // CV_32F is data type for matrix elements
   Mat out(rows, cols, CV_32F, Scalar(0));
   ```
2. Set regions of interest (ROI) in your output matrix to desired sub-matrices. For example

   ```
   // your input matrices
   Mat R, T; 

   // set ROI for R
   cv::Rect rect_R(0, 0, R.rows, R.cols);
   cv::Mat out_R = out(rect_R);
   // this assignment does not copy data
   // out and out_R now share data

   // assign out_R to R
   out_R = R;

   // similarly you can set another area of out to matrix T, etc.
   ```
3. `out` is set. you are done.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but for some reason, the copy is not happening. I faced the same with many methods. The value of Z seems to be all 0's, instead of the format am expecting. Can you please help me here?

Comment: what's Z? What do you mean copy is not happening? Where do you have problems exactly?

Comment: Did you create R and T matrices first?

Comment: What is the type of R and T matrices (32 bit float - CV_32F, unsigned char - CV_8U, or signed 32 bit integer CV_32S, etc)? output matrix should be created with the same type.

Comment: every matrix is of type 64_CS1. My apologies, the error was elsewhere. The method is working fine. Thank you :).